# Coldfusion Encrypt & Decrypt Within Functions In A Component

Tags: ajax, encryption, coldfusion

We're having this issue where we are unable to decrypt a string we encrypted. It's a bit more complex then that, but that is what needs solving.

```
<cfset URLString = "https://someurl/report/somereport?date=12/27/2017&areaid=25&districtid=111&region=southwest&city=Tampa&localekey=X999&localename=Ybor&informed=true">
<cfset FindTheQ = Find('?', URLString)>
<cfset MinusTheQ = Val(FindTheQ + 1)>
<cfset BaseURL = Left(URLString, FindTheQ)>
<cfset URLStringLength = Len(URLString)>
<cfset TheVariables = Mid(URLString, MinusTheQ, URLStringLength)>
<cfset SecretKey=GenerateSecretKey("AES")>

<cfset Encrypted = encrypt(TheVariables, SecretKey, "AES", "HEX") />
<cfset Decrypted = decrypt(Encrypted, SecretKey, "AES", "HEX") />
<cfset CompleteURL = BaseURL & Decrypted>

<cfoutput>
URLString: #URLString#<BR><BR>
BaseURL: #BaseURL#<BR><BR>
Variables: #TheVariables#<BR><BR>
Encrypted: #Encrypted#<BR><BR>
Decrypted: #Decrypted#<BR><BR>
CompleteURL: #CompleteURL#<BR><BR>
</cfoutput>
```

So above is a nice little test cfm page that works great. We get a string that is a URL. We extract it into two parts, the BaseURL and TheVariables. The idea is to encrypt TheVariables but not the BaseURL. Then we decrypt TheVariables, and concatenate with the BaseURL for the CompleteURL. I output them at the bottom to display how it works. Yay!

However, in the "real world" it's not one simple cfm page. In the real code, it's a component within the controller of a cfwheels framework with a separate encrypt and decrypt function being called with Javascript and Ajax. Sheesh!  So assume all the related code exists to the two functions below (I included the minimum for readability.

```
<cfcomponent extends="Controller">
    <cffunction name="EncryptLink">
        <cfset SecretKey = "WTq8zYcZfaWVvMncigHqwQ==">

        <cfset FindTheQ = Find('?', URL.URLString)>
        <cfset MinusTheQ = Val(FindTheQ + 1)>
        <cfset BaseURL = Left(URL.URLString, FindTheQ)>
        <cfset URLStringLength = Len(URL.URLString)>
        <cfset TheVariables = Mid(URL.URLString, MinusTheQ, URLStringLength)>
        <cfset Encrypted = encrypt(TheVariables, SecretKey, "AES", "Base64") />
        <cfset CompleteURL = BaseURL & Encrypted>

        <cfreturn renderText(CompleteURL)>
   </cffunction>

   <cffunction name="DecryptLink">
       <cfset SecretKey = "WTq8zYcZfaWVvMncigHqwQ==">

       <cfset FindTheQ = Find('?', URL.URLString)>
       <cfset MinusTheQ = Val(FindTheQ + 1)>
       <cfset BaseURL = Left(URL.URLString, FindTheQ)>
       <cfset URLStringLength = Len(URL.URLString)>
       <cfset TheVariables = Mid(URL.URLString, MinusTheQ, URLStringLength)>

       <cfset Decrypted = decrypt(TheVariables, SecretKey, "AES", "Base64")>
       <cfset CompleteURL = BaseURL & Decrypted>

       <cfreturn renderText(CompleteURL)>
   </cffunction>
```

The result from the encrypt function is exactly what we want. It works! Yay again! However, when the decrypt function runs it brings back the first part, the BaseURL correctly, but the Decrypted part comes back random characters and those black diamonds with the question marks in them. Which means it's not being interpreted.

Additional:

- The GenerateSecretKey function won't work for us since it will generate a new key when link is clicked to come in to be decrypted.
- We've tried AES, DES, & Blowfish encryptions.
- We've tried it with base64, UU, and hex encodings.
- The renderText() function is for cfwheels and just returns the text you
  specify. It is useful as a response to AJAX requests.

Comment: I think the URLStringLength should be Len(URLString)-FindTheQ+1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Answer based on [the original code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48670448/1))

> The result from the encrypt function is exactly what we want.

Actually, it's not.

The string logic is slightly off, so BaseURL includes one too many characters. The first char of the query string ("d" in this case) gets added to the variables string. That changes the encrypted value, which is why it won't decrypt.

- `BaseURL`: https://someurl/report/somereport?**d**
- `Variables`: ?**d**ate=12/27/2017&...
- `Encrypted`: **771D3386211040E83B0FD64F25**...
- `CompleteURL`: https://someurl/report/somereport?**d**771D3386211040E83B0FD64F25...

I'm assuming that isn't the real Decrypt() code, since the arguments don't match those used for Encrypt(). The params should be:

```
decrypt(TheVariables, SecretKey, "AES", "HEX")
```

A few other suggestions:

1. Using list functions (with delimiter `?`) would simplify the code a LOT
2. `Local` scope all function variables
3. Use the `arguments` scope for parameters, instead of using `URL` directly

Comment: Hi, It looks like I hadn't copied the functions precisely as the related code in test page. I did it again and still got the correct variables for BaseURL and The Variables.

Comment: Can you update the question code so we can see the "correct" values you're getting? What about the Decrypt() arguments? (If it were me, I'd use list functions instead. Code is shorter and easier to follow imo).

Comment: I added back in the decrypt(TheVariables, SecretKey, "AES", "HEX") and it works now. I guess a combination of both those things was it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. Might also consider updating the code to use list functions... much simpler :-)

Comment: Which list functions would you be referring to?

Comment: ListFirst (to get baseurl) and ListRest (get query string) with `?` delimiter.

Comment: [For example](https://trycf.com/gist/93bae6563514025d4a0388636bf66d7e/acf11?theme=monokai). Obviously it needs validation, but that provides the jist...